# Add JSON provider for CXF JAX-RS in Spring Boot properties or YAML file

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

How to move `endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());` into an application properties file?

```
 @Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(asList(new CustomerServiceDefault()));
        endpoint.setAddress("/");
        endpoint.setFeatures(asList(new Swagger2Feature()));
        return endpoint.create();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you haven't done so already, you have to add the dependency with the provider:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you need to add the package with Jackson entity providers for JAX-RS scanning (`org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` in this case), together with other packages you created. I'm using yaml configuration and class scanning as opposed to component scanning, and here is how it looks:

```
cxf:
  path: /services
  servlet.init: 
    service-list-path: /info
  jaxrs:
    classes-scan: true
    classes-scan-packages: com.yourcompany.package.with.your.handlers,org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs
```

Comment: How can I do this with GSON

Comment: Sorry, I've only used it with Jackson @amod - maybe someone else knows...

Comment: I asked a question but no response over there too. But I ended up using Jackson. Can you tell me what package I should use for Jackson version 2?

Comment: They've switched to `com.fasterxml.jackson` @amod

Comment: Here's my Gradle dependency:
`compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.8.8'` @amod

Comment: I am using maven. Let me add this dependency in Maven and get back. Thanks